# Importing CustomDocumentProperties from Word to Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, custom-properties

I am trying to pull CustomDocumentProperties from a Word Document (that I select using Application.GetOpenFilename) to an Excel Sheet.

I can get the to run code using the number of the item:

```
    Set ExcelRange = Range("DataFields")
    
    For r = 1 To ExcelRange.Rows.Count Step 1
        
        ExcelWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 3) = WordDoc.CustomDocumentProperties(r).Value
                                 
    Next r
```

If I hard code the name of the custom property, it also works:

```
Set ExcelRange = Range("DataFields")

For r = 1 To ExcelRange.Rows.Count Step 1

    ExcelWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 3) = WordDoc.CustomDocumentProperties("Subject Name").Value

Next r
```

Obviously in this case, it returns the "Subject Name" 7 times).

I don't want to return all the values - only specific ones based on the values of a named range (in this case DataFields).

DataFields references A1:A7. I would like to take those cells(that contain the names of the custom properties) and paste the value of the corresponding custom properties in C1:C7

However, I can seem to get the code to return values in C1:C7 based on the values in A1:A7.

Based on my (limited) knowledge, I thought that the following would return the desired results, but it's not working for me:

```
    Set ExcelRange = Range("DataFields")
    
    For r = 1 To ExcelRange.Rows.Count Step 1
        
        ExcelWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 3) = WordDoc.CustomDocumentProperties(ExcelRange(r, 1))
        
    Next r
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you forget to put `.value` at the end? (`...= WordDoc.CustomDocumentProperties(ExcelRange(r, 1)).value`)

Comment: Unfortunately, whether I include the .value or not, it still produces an error - Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument.

Comment: Sorry I think maybe I typed that wrong and it should have been `...= WordDoc.CustomDocumentProperties(ExcelRange(r, 1).value)`

Comment: Thank you for trying, but that did not work either.

Comment: Someone provided a response to me outside this forum and was able to resolve my issue.